# codec required in Windows Media Player 11

Tags: windows, windows-media-player

can someone tell me how to resolve this "codec required" if I play an `.avi` video with my media player. it's version 11. and I'm using Windows XP.

Comment: Does anyone know how to have this video work: i can't see it here in my browser:

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetID=HA102819681033&ns=MSACCESS&lcid=1033

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and install [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_codec_pack.htm) to your machine, and you'll be able to play them.

**EDIT:** The video you want to watch seems to need ACELP Codec. Download and install this codec from the following link and try again:

[ACELP Codec](http://www.voiceage.com/acelp_eval_eula.php) (Scroll down the page for downloading options)

Comment: which one should I install? I had so many choices, basic, minor, standard.

Comment: I use the standard one.

Comment: hi thanks but it was not still working. I used win 7 now from my work and I have this video from Microsoft site, which I wanted to watch but it's just connecting and there's no video coming out: http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetID=HA102819681033&ns=MSACCESS&lcid=1033

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: thanks you're very helpful I will try that now and see how it goes :-)

Comment: i selected the "accept and download the version for all other window users" is this correct, since I'm not using Vista

Comment: When I installed it, it's only for the audio codec not for video?:-(

Comment: Yes, the one you chose is correct. If it couldn't solve the problem, you should go through the **each step** in the following link: [Troubleshoot video and audio](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HP010842249990&lcid=1033&NS=MSACCESS&Version=12&CTT=5&origin=HA010281968).

Comment: that's what I also did. But none of them works. I usually do the steps that I can before I ask for help, just to make sure if that I didn't miss something. Were you able to play the video in your side then?

Comment: I can't check at the moment because I am on a limited-account computer here at work.

Comment: I see, thanks for checking that for me. I'm not sure how to see this one then.... :-(

Comment: You're welcome. Hope I could help...

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same link to the office.microsoft.com video on my computer, which has zillions of codecs installed, and the link doesn't work.

Both Firefox and IE give the same result : The video doesn't play. When I click on Play, the player status changes momentarily to "Connecting to media" then returns to "Ready", no matter how many times I click on Play.

The problem is probably on the other side with the Microsoft media server.

Comment: that's true. same problem here, no matter how many times I clicked on play it is still the same. do you think it's from the microsoft media server?

Comment: In addition, none of my add-ons for downloading video detect any kind of video streaming going on while it is Connecting to media. So in my opinion, streaming simply fails to even start on this video.

Comment: thanks also for your idea. any idea then how to see this video? Do I need to contact Microsoft for this?

Comment: I think this is the contact page : http://support.microsoft.com/contactus/?ws=support&CTT=114. They even have a "Chat Now" button. Open this page in IE because this is Microsoft. Prepare a short problem description first in a text file with the video link, to be able to paste everything into the chat window.

Comment: the microsoft chat support is the most complicated one. there are so many things that you need to fill out, until I gave it up. It's not actually a support, because first the site is not a user friendly :-(

Comment: I do see this as a support question, because Microsoft is responsible for its website. Maybe Customer Service at Product Sales & General Inquiries will be easier to contact: https://support.microsoft.com/contactus/emailcontact.aspx?scid=sw;en;1539&ws=corpinfo&ws=support&ws=support

Comment: I will try that. And will let you know. I was able to chat with the technical support but what she can do to me is, direct me to a site where I can post my question. It was not really of big help :-( But will try the other link you gave.